# Woocommerce - Show "Local Pickup" only when a coupon is added

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I have scoured the internet, but have not seen anything that speaks to what I'm trying to accomplish. Essentially, at the checkout screen, I have shipping & handling set to a flat rate of $4.99. I am using a coupon code to enable free shipping, but I want to offer the user the choice of local pickup if they enter the coupon code. In my shipping zone, I've enabled all three shipping options (flat rate, free shipping, local pickup) unfortunately, with this approach, local pickup shows up by default as a second option to $4.99 shipping & handling.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)